# Which is a good JavaScript driver for Neo4j?

Tags: javascript, node.js, neo4j

I know there are couple of good options out there like Thingdom's node-neo4j, Seraph, Cypher-stream. I want to kind of test how each of them are in terms ease of use, versatility in writing queries and library is continuously updated. Personally, my favourite is Seraph, as their APIs are too the point..plus it gives the ability to execute raw Cypher queries too.

I would just like to know what your opinions are, which is your favourite and why?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

From terms of maintenance and robustness node-neo4j v2 is most widely used also in production.

Seraph is only partially updated to the lasted Cypher endpoints.

Going forward for Neo4j 3.0 you can also look into the official js-driver for the binary protocol: https://www.npmjs.com/package/neo4j-driver

Comment: Thanks....checking their docs